# Remove property from metadata using packaging 2

Tags: custom-object, salesforcedx, custom-metadata, packaging-2

We're using packaging 2.0 (SFDX) to develop and create our package, but have made a mistake and wound up with `<externalSharingModel>ReadWrite</externalSharingModel>` in a custom object. That might not have been so bad, but we then created a package with that in the code on to realize that it prevents our package from being installed in orgs with External Sharing Model disabled (which is the default).

Now, we have an issue where just removing the tag and trying to build a package from that doesn't appear to actually remove the tag from the metadata. The same installation error occurs. We've also tried to just change the value of the tag, but SFDC still errors about the property being there at all.

Is there any way to remove this tag?

This is the error from file `My_Request__c.object-meta.xml`:

```
Can't specify an external sharing model for My_Request__c
```

Comment: I have the same issue as you, I asked about it in the Packaging 2 Beta Chatter group: https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000Lg5U&fId=0D53A00003SAo9O

Comment: I also asked about a way to disable this setting when creating a Scratch Org here, don't hesitate to comment and add your voice to the request: https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000HTp1&fId=0D53A00003SQizw

Comment: FWIW, I created a new package and that didn't work. Same issue. Maybe because it's the same namespace or the same packaging org?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's now working again.
As said in Chatter, something was fixed on Salesforce side.
I had to recreate a new package2 version (again without externalSharingModel), same source as before, but now it's working.